# Why my PKCS#12 (generated by openssl) canot be read by java

Tags: java, openssl, keytool, pkcs#12

OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips

openjdk-17.0.1

I use Openssl to generate PKCS12 file. My java keystore canot read it.

My openssl cmds:(rootca.key is privatekey and rootca.crt is selfSigned certificate.)

`openssl req -new -newkey ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:prime256v1 -nodes -keyout out.key -out out.csr -subj /C=CN/CN=-1040310296`

`openssl x509 -req -CA rootca.crt -CAkey rootca.key -days 365 -in out.csr -out out.crt -CAcreateserial -extensions v3_ca -extfile ./openssl.cnf`

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in out.crt -inkey out.key -chain -CAfile rootca.crt -name server -out out.p12 -password pass:Ff5evzT0tr`

When i use my java programme to read this PKCS12 file, exceptions caught:

Java code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(p12keyI, "Ff5evzT0tr".toCharArray());
```

Exceptions:

```
java.io.IOException: Tag number over 30 is not supported
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:414)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:459)
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2012)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
```

I can read it by openssl cmd:
`openssl pkcs12 -in out.p12 -password pass:Ff5evzT0tr -info -nodes`

I canot read it by java programme and keytool cmd:
`keytool -list -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore output.p12 -storepass Ff5evzT0tr`

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2159)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:946)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:415)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:408)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Only named ECParameters supported
        ... 6 more
```

I wanna to know what cause this problem and how to fix it.
Thx all

Comment: I update my openssl to version 1.1.1t 2023. This problem disappears.